# How to make reactjs recharts legends to next line in case of overflow of width?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, recharts

I am using Stackedbarchart in recharts.org in react js. Everything is coming fine but because of long list of items the legends are getting way out of the width. So how to break legends into multiple lines within specified width?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Legend wrapperStyle={{width:510,whiteSpace:"break-spaces"}} />
```

we need to add our style in wrapperStyle in legend. so whiteSpace property will break into multiple lines if width extended.